# How can I show and hide a table row using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a regular HTML table, how can I show and hide a table row using jQuery?

Comment: Show/hide them based on what? Some type of user interaction?

Answer (score 4):

Hides every 5th row:

```
$('tr:nth(5)).hide()
```

An example: http://jsbin.com/epeto

Answer (score 1):

Either iterate the tr elements inside your table or add id's to your trs and calling the show/hide function in jQuery with that ID

Answer (score 1):

Also, you might want to look at the .toggle() function.

```
$('tr:nth(5)).toggle()
```

This will show/hide it and continually switch...

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Nuno's answer above, JQuery's [toggle()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle) function may also be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

I would steer clear of the show and hide methods for table rows. They lead to bad ui effects x-browser. I have found fadeIn/Out to work much better x-browser.